# Kerr Effect; Electro-refraction

Tags: energy, visible-light, refraction

First post here. is is possible to observe the [Kerr effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_effect) in transparent materials, at low voltages (such as 3.8V)?

If so, can you refract light enough to distort an image, in a way similar to that of a magnifiying glass / glass lens?

I read the post here ([Is Kerr effect in glass observable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106475/is-kerr-effect-in-glass-observable)) but it doesn't directly answer if it is possible in materials other than glass. I'm thinking there may be the equivalent of 'superconductors', that display the kerr effect at very low applied electrical fields.

Comment: Is it possible? Probably, if you are trying an experiment in insane experimental sensitivity. Would it be useful? No. Even in the best of materials the constant is small, on the order of 1e-12m/V^2, which tells you that you need electric fields of thousands of V/m to get reasonable changes in polarization. If you want to achieve basically the same thing with a small field and switching time doesn't matter... use a liquid crystal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the nonlinear effects are threshold-less, i.e. they happen at any magnitude of electric field, however, the smaller the field is the higher the accuracy of measurement has to be.

Here I would like to introduce you an effect I think it relates to your question of:

> can you refract light enough to distort an image, in a way similar to that of a magnifiying glass / glass lens

I should say that this effect happens in optical filaments. When a femtosecond optical pulse  with a certain power which is called ''critical power'' is traveling in air or transparent media, because of its high electric field a positive refractive index **due to Kerr effect**  causes the beam to focus (I can elaborate more about the filament if you are interested). But the point here is, it is shown that two filaments that are propagating in parallel and close to each other sometimes can absorb or repel each other which is essentially the same as refraction that you are asking about. However still the electric field responsible for this effect is relatively large.